# Inertial Frames -- Kleppner and Kolenkow's Problem 1.19

Tags: reference-frames, inertial-frames

Kleppner and Kolenkow's *An Introduction to Mechanics* has the following question:

[image]

I get how to solve it, but I have a conceptual query. Particle/point $B$ is executing uniform circular motion with respect to the center of the circle, $O$. It's velocity vector doesn't change in magnitude but definitely changes in direction due to the centripetal acceleration. So, isn't $B$ an accelerating frame of reference with respect to $O$?

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  Rotating frames of reference are accelerating reference frames.

Comment: So, how does one answer this question? My solution assume that we have an intertidal frame (B) and using arguments related to relative velocity, I come up with an answer -- which matches solutions given on a few websites. Is this the wrong approach then? If so, then why does the text give this as a question in the first chapter -- accelerating frames are discussed much later on -- and asks us to solve it using the idea of relative motion.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Can we go by making a simplifying assumption? I sort of blindly solved this question without thinking of this caveat.

Comment: Sample solution: https://scienceanswers.wordpress.com/2012/04/17/problem-1-15b-page-48/ Note: it's just much neater/less tedious to solve it in Cartesian coordinates. The solution just makes it look more cumbersome/laborious.

Comment: This is purely a kinematics question.  There are no forces involved.  What assumptions are you making that depend on it being an inertial frame?

Comment: See the attached link. That's exactly how I initially solved but upon giving it a second thought I'm a bit confused: with respect to O, isn't B accelerating, where the magnitude is given by the centripetal acceleration. Doesn't that make B an accelerating frame, disallowing me to change the frame and observe how A is moving in B. Or am I simply  confusing myself? There is a centripetal force/acceleration involved; this doesn't make it a purely kinematic a problem right? Isn't that why you made the argument: yeah, B is an accelerating/rotating/non intertidal frame?

Comment: Wait, I think I get it: with respect to O, A is accelerating since the velocity vector's direction changes and note magnitude. If you see the calculation in the link, with respect to B, A's velocity vector has the same direction but oscillating magnitude. Clearly, according to my hunch we're transforming between intertial and non intertial frames -- and there are forces involved -- centripetal with respect to O and at least Corlois with respect to B. But the question doesn't concern us with that -- it says, hey...find the velocity vector, never mind if B is an intertial frame or not?

Comment: I think what's going on here is that the reference frame of *b* is not rotating in the sense that the basis vectors *i* and *j* are always in the same direction.  *b* is just translating, like in part (a) of the question.

Comment: Right but besides that point, doesn't the particle B accelerate with respect to O -- due to the change in the direction of B's velocity vector. If this condition fails, then B can't be intertial, right? Let's just compare the velocity vectors with respect to O and B. With respect to O, it only changes magnitude; with respect to B, magnitude (and direction). See the link. So since the accelerations are changing, the transformation can't be from one intertial frame to the other right? Leading me to make the claim in my last comment, based on your observation that it's a purely kinematics prob.